# /msg alternative in empathy messanger

Tags: empathy

I was trying to join a chat room in freenode. The freenode faq says to use `/msg nickserv register <password> <email>` to register an account. I'm using Empathy messenger. It says `/msg` is not a valid command. Any idea? Is there an alternative for for `/msg` in Empathy?

Comment: have you tried `/ns` in place of `/msg nickserv` ?

Answer (score 1):

some commands have been added in Empathy 2.29.2, such as /say /nick /join /j /msg /query and /help